# Configuring S3 bucket as alternative storage for Dovecot sdbox

Tags: dovecot, amazon-s3, s3fs

I'm trying to use an S3 bucket for long-term storage for emails, served with Dovecot, with a cron job to `doveadm altmove` everything older than a few weeks to alternative storage. I've been able to accomplish this with the following Dovecot configuration

```ini
# doveconf
mail_location = sdbox:~/sdbox:ALT=/var/s3mail/%n
```

where `/var/s3mail` is the root directory for my S3 bucket of choice, mounted with [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse).

This works for moving old emails to the alternative storage, freeing up space on my mail server's box. However, when trying to move old emails (stored on S3) between mailbox folders using my email client, Dovecot fails with the following log message:

```
link(/var/s3mail/[SOURCE_PATH], /var/s3mail/[DEST_PATH]/.temp....) failed: Operation not supported
```

Given `link` I'd guess this is a shortfall of S3's or s3fs-fuse's filesystem capabilities.

How might I accomplish the end goal of using an S3 bucket for alternative storage if not through s3fs-fuse and the above configuration, preferably without changing the storage method (sdbox)?

Alternatively, is there a configuration to change the way Dovecot moves emails between folders, so as to not use hard links? I can use symlinks with s3fs-fuse, but not hard links. (I'm taking `link` in the error to mean Dovecot's trying to create a hard link, but this may be misinterpretation. I don't know much about Dovecot's implementation.)

Comment: You are right that `link()` is the syscall to create a hard link.  Link and unlink is a very efficient way of moving a file to a new path within one filesystem.  S3 does not support hard links and in fact does not even have a "move" or "rename" operation -- renaming/moving objects in S3 requires copying the object to a new path and then deleting the original.  It's a reasonable architecture for what S3 is, but not well suited to this purpose.

Comment: Incidentally, S3 now has an officially supported Linux mount client, which would definitely not work for this setup, either... and I would suggest that this fact serves as confirmation that S3 isn't a good choice for this use case.  You wouldn't get the kind of performance you need, even if it did work.
 https://github.com/awslabs/mountpoint-s3/blob/main/doc/SEMANTICS.md

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot So then, out of curiosity, do you know why Dovecot handles moving a file from primary to alternate storage differently from moving a file within alternate storage? Does it detect/assume they're different filesystems and not use `link()`?

Answer (score 0):

EFS works, and actually seems better suited for email hosting than S3, so I'm using that now.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW you can use [obox](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/obox/) with [S3](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/obox/s3/) storage to do this. Actually you can store it all in `obox` and use lifecycle rules to push older objects into cheaper storage automatically.

I’d prefer this to using FUSE-mounted S3 buckets, which I’ve always found to be kludgy. S3 is fast enough for IMAP and cheaper than EFS.

Given Dovecot’s stated direction to only closed source for Dovecot 3 (see the video on the bottom of [the page](https://www.open-xchange.com/products/dovecot-pro/)), migrating to another server might make sense.